# Azure Function App endpoint stuck on 'running' but has already finished running

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-functions-runtime

I have a Durable Function App (Elastic Premium) that gets triggered via Azure Data Factory. In ADF I have an activity that checks the runtime status of the activity that was triggered. However, I have an activity whose endpoint shows 'Running':
[image]

However, if I check the status of this run on de Azure Function App portal, I can see that it has already finished successfully
[image]

Any idea on what this could be?

For more context, all of the activities that were triggered after this one are stuck either on Running or in Pending.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I took the Azure durable Function API in an Azure Data Factory Instance and mapped the Function API Settings accordingly:

[image]

[image]

Both the Function Status in the data studio and runtime status of the durable function API is success and completed.

If your activity function code is taking more time to process the request by that instance then the runtimestatus will be in Running State. Check the function timeout setting or request-response time of that function API.

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management?tabs=csharp) for more information on **`runtimeStatus`** of the Azure Durable Function APIs.